# Switch/pulse signal DPDT relay inconsistently switching polarity

Tags: switches, relay, signal, dpdt

I am trying to use a momentary switch to switch polarity of a motor using the linked device. It switches sometimes, but it is inconsistent. Below is the schematic of how I have the motor hooked up to the relay. I’m wondering if I’m doing something wrong, or if the relay is bad. I don’t understand why it works sometimes but not others. Any help is appreciated.

Note: I tested voltage. The relay shows it is switching properly based on the LEDs; it is engaging; but the polarity only switches sometimes

[ELECTRONICS-SALON Panel Mount Momentary-Switch/Pulse-Signal Control Latching DPDT Relay Module,12V](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B015MSYQ8Q/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_TNSDCT68VMVESDTR6P4G?_encoding=UTF8&psc=)

This only shows half connected to motor at c1 and c2. Battery switches between nc1, no1, nc2, and no2

Any suggestions on a different relay that will work with momentary switches since this one is lacking would be helpful as well

Here is the data sheet: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1dObBA3eJL.pdf

[image: schematic]

[image: schematic of relay]

Comment: I’m only showing the half connected to the motor. The other half is working properly. The relay switch is dual and connects c1 and c2 either to no1, nc1, no2, or nc2.  I added the photo For the schematic I was given

Comment: There's no need to comment on your own question. [Edit] the details into it so that readers don't miss them in the comments. Then you can delete the comment.

Comment: As usual, Amazon supplies no datasheet. "*No datasheet? No sale!*" Read through the reviews and you'll find a lot of problems with the device. You might find the solution there too.

Comment: The motor connects to c1 and c2… this was just from my notes… I commented on my own question bc someone gave me a comment about how I used the wrong symbol for a relay and then deleted it

Comment: @Transistor I found a data sheet online and used that https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1dObBA3eJL.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help from those who commented… I hooked it up to a power supply and used it to realize there is a short because I used the same battery to power the motor and the relay. I need a diode or a separate power supply and the issue goes away. Thought the solution might be helpful for others with the same issue